# How to build an image upload object and append to request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image

i am trying to build an image upload object and append to a request in Laravel.

I currently have a middleware that intercepts requests and check if there are base64 image strings in it and if there are, it converts it to image object and appends it back to the request.

I have been unsuccessful in appending the converted images back to the request as an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` i have tried a few things the closest thing i found was `UploadedFile::fake()->image('avatar.jpg');` but how can i use my own base64 converted image instead of the generate fake image as looking through the [UploadedFile Api](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.html) i could not come up with a solution.

This is what i have so far

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

    class Base64EncodedImageHandler
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if ($request->has('photos')) {

                $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'photos' => 'nullable|array|filled',
                    'photos.*' => 'required_unless:photos,'.null.'|image',
                ]);

                if ($validator->fails()) {

                    $images = collect($request->input('photos'))->map(function ($item, $key) {

                        if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $item)) {
                            $data = substr($item, strpos($item, ',') + 1);

                            $data = base64_decode($data);

                            // Testing to see if the image decoding worked
                            // Storage::disk('local')->put("public/test/".uniqid().".png", $data);


                            // Build image object


                            return $data;

                        }

                        return $item;
                    });

                    $request = $request->merge(['photos' => $images]);

                }

                // Dumping request object here
                dd($request);

            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Based on the answers i got i was able to achieve my initial objective as so

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
    use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;

    class Base64EncodedImageHandler
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @author Sayra
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            // Add an additional method
            $request::macro('setConvertedFiles', function ($files) {
                $this->convertedFiles = $files;
                return $this;
            });

            if ($request->has('portrait')) {

                $images = collect($request->input('portrait'))->map(function ($item, $key) {

                    if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $item)) {
                        $item = substr($item, strpos($item, ',') + 1);
                        $image = base64_decode($item);

                        $path = 'public/test/';
                        $name = uniqid();
                        $extension = '.jpg';

                        // Store converted file
                        if (Storage::put($path.$name, $image)){

                            return new UploadedFile(storage_path('app/').$path.$name, $name.$extension, 'image/jpeg');
                        }
                    }

                })->all();

                // Added base64 converted files to request, clear base64 params
                $photos = $request->photos? $request->photos : [];
                $merge = array_merge($photos, $images);
                $request->setConvertedFiles(['photos' => $merge]);
                $request->merge(['photos' => $merge]);
                $request->merge(['portrait' => []]);



                // the isValid() method fails as the file was not a direct upload
                dd($request->file('photos.0')->isValid(),$request->file('photos'),$request);

            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

My current and only issue is that when `isValid` or `is_uploaded_file()` is called the image is seen as an invalid image i would like to properly fake the image upload so that the base64 converted images will work and go through the same process as the normal images. Thanks.

Comment: i have been down this road and am guessing your front end engineer felt it was convenient for him/her to submit base64 images rather that build an actual image object? anyways my suggestion would be https://github.com/hshn/base64-encoded-file have a look at the package but i would advice just handle the base64 submissions separately trying to combine both will just lead to endless frustrations. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile` to create image object (you should first save your base64 file somewhere temporary, since `UploadedFile` requires path). Then in your `Base64EncodedImageHandler` use trait `Illuminate\Http\Concerns\InteractsWithInput`.

You will need this method: `protected function convertUploadedFiles(array $files)` which accepts array of symfony UploadedFile. This will make `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` object. Now when you say `$request->merge(['photos' => $images])` your 'photos' will be array of UploadedFile objects which you can manipulate.

I am not sure, but maybe your `$request->file()` will be still empty. If this is true you can create new request, fill it with all other data from original one, but for files give converted UploadedFile array.

Also check this https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10791#issuecomment-213529251
They are using custom `FormRequest` trait to overwrite `->all()` method. You may try the same with `->allFiles()` or even overwrite `$files` property. Keep in mind it accepts `FileBag`, not `array`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it took me some time to figure things out and like you said `$request->file()` remained empty :( i tried `$request->convertedFiles = $images` but it was a protected variable.

Comment: $request->convertedFiles it's a protected property, not variable ;)